# Use a function that needs UITableView in another view?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, core-data

In my **`WalletTableViewController`** I have two functions, used to calculate the `Wallet Value`:

**A.** `updateCellValue()` Is called by `reloadData()` with the `tableView` and uses `indexPath.row` to fetch a `value` (price) and an `amount` (number of coins) corresponding to the cell and make a calculation to get the total value of that coin (amountValue = value * amount). That is then saved with Core Data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

    updateCellValue(cell, atRow: indexPath.row)

    return cell
}

func updateCellValue(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell, atRow row: Int) {

    var newCryptos : [CryptosMO] = []
    var doubleAmount = 0.0

    if CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        newCryptos = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()!
    }

    cryptoPrice = cryptos[row].code!

    guard let cryptoDoublePrice = CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] else { return }

    let selectedAmount = newCryptos[row]

    guard let amount = selectedAmount.amount else { return }
    var currentAmountValue = selectedAmount.amountValue

    doubleAmount = Double(amount)!

    let calculation = cryptoDoublePrice * doubleAmount
    currentAmountValue = String(calculation)

    CoreDataHandler.editObject(editObject: selectedAmount, amount: amount, amountValue: currentAmountValue)

    updateWalletValue()
}
```

**B.** `updateWalletValue()` Is a function that fetches all the `amountValue` objects in Core Data and adds them together to calculate the `Wallet Value`.

```
func updateWalletValue() {

    var items : [CryptosMO] = []

    if CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        items = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()!
    }

    total = items.reduce(0.0, { $0 + Double($1.amountValue)! } )

    WalletTableViewController.staticTotal = total

}
```

**In my `MainViewController`, the `Wallet Value` is displayed too, but how can I refresh it's value?**

```
func updateMainVCWalletLabel() {

   //... what can I do here??

}
```

**This works great for the `WalletViewController`** of course with the `TableView` and `indexPath`, but **how can I call `updateCellValue` from the `MainViewController` to keep the value updated?**

The `WalletViewController` is instantiated and pushed from the `MainViewController` :

```
@IBAction func walletButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let walletViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "walletTableViewController")
    self.present(walletViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You can use `Notification` for this. Observe the notification where you want to update the value and fire it whenever data got changed.

Comment: Don't repost questions. Improve your question. For example add the information how both view controllers are related

Comment: @vadian This is what I was trying to ask yesterday but as nobody seemed to get it I thought my question was so bad I would ask a new one

Comment: @TheTiger I updated my question with more precisions

Comment: @martin Yes! Did you try `Notification` ?

Comment: @TheTiger I did, but he app crashes because I can't `reloadData()` from `MainViewController` as the `tableView` is in `WalletViewController`.

Comment: Once again, the information is missing how the controllers are related to each other. Storyboard? No storyboard? Xib? Segue? Instantiation? I suggested in your previous question to keep a reference to the wallet controller and use that.

Comment: Make a function for whole calculation in any `singleton` class or may be in `AppDelegate` and which doesn't depend on any `UI` and use this function throughout the application.

Comment: @vadian Sorry about that, I've added the infos.

Comment: If you are in  `WalletViewController` then `self.presentingViewController` will be your `MainViewController` and you can call the method which will refresh `MainViewController` by this instance.

Comment: You might want to provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to clearly depict what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a single method in multiple view controllers you should implement that method where you can call that method from anywhere. For example you can use singleton class here.

1. Create a swift file and name it as your wish (like WalletHelper or WalletManager)
2. Then you will get a file with the following format

```swift
    class WalletHelper: NSObject
    {

    }
```

3. Create a shared instance for that class

```swift
    static let shared = WalletHelper()
```

4. Implement the method you want

```swift
    func getWalletValue() -> Float {
        // write your code to get wallet value`
       // and return the calculated value
    }
```

5. Finally call that method like

```swift
    let walletValue = WalletHelper.shared. getWalletValue()
```

WalletHelper.swift looks like

```swift
import UIKit

class WalletHelper: NSObject
{
    static let shared = WalletHelper()

    func getWalletValue() -> Float {
        // write your code to get wallet value
        // and return the calculated value
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this allow me to call `reloadData()` on a `tableView` located in another `view controller`?

Answer (score 0):

**Update** (old answer below)

To me it is absolutly unclear what you want to achieve: Which value do you want to be updated? The `staticTotal`? 
Seems a litte like an [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. As @vadian commented yesterday, please clearly describe where the data is stored, how the controllers are connected, what you want to update when in order to achieve what. You could also provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes clear what you are asking, instead of adding more and more code snippets.

**And, even more interesting**:  Why do you *modify* CoreData entries (`CoreDataHandler.editObject`) when you are in the call stack of `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)`? **Never ever** ever do so! You are in a *reading* case - `reloadData` is intended to update the table *view* to reflect the data changes *after* the data has been changed. It is *not* intended to update the data itself. `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` is called many many times, especially when the user scrolls up and down, so you are causing large write impacts (and therefore: performance losses) when you write into the database.

---

**Old Post**

You could just call `reloadData` on the table view, which then will update it's cells.

There are also a few issues with your code:

- Why do you call `updateWalletValue()` that frequently? Every time a cell is being displayed, it will be called, run through the whole database and do some reduce work. You should cache the value and only update it if the data itself is modified
- Why do you call `fetchObject()` twice (in `updateWalletValue()`)?

You should do this:

```
func updateWalletValue() {

    guard let items:[CryptosMO] = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() else {
        WalletTableViewController.staticTotal = 0.0
        return
    }

    total = items.reduce(0.0, { $0 + Double($1.amountValue)! } )

    WalletTableViewController.staticTotal = total
}
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, calling `reloadData` from `MainViewController` crashes, which makes sense because the `tableView` is not displayed.

Comment: If it's not displayed, why would you want to update the cells (which are also not displayed)? Please be more precise of what you want to update when.

Comment: I tried to edit the question better, I need to update the `total` FROM `MainViewController`, which is impossible right now with `updateCellValue(cell, atRow: indexPath.row)`